# Font (Myanmar3) not showing correctly in pdf

Tags: java

I want to get the right myanmar font in the pdf file but can't get it although I'm using mm3.ttf in the font. It shows the myanmar font but not correctly as it shows it in reverse. It doesn't work (in the browser I'm using the same ttf)

```
PdfWriter writer=PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(cardprint_file));
final String FONT = ServerSession.serverPath + "WEB-INF/font/mm3.ttf";
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont( FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font font = new Font(bf, 12);
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
Phrase name = new Phrase(data.get(i).getMname(), font);
```

Comment: Could you please share us even you have tired source, then wen can give answer here without how do we know, what kind of technique you are using to do it?

Comment: it is not clear dear

Comment: I wrote these above codes,it contains right font data in "Phrase name = new Phrase(data.get(i).getMname(), font);" in this line....but in pdf file my data in myanmar fonts are reverse.